# React Native Expo Google Fonts: is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync

Tags: react-native, fonts, expo

I'm using Expo Google Fonts and the useFonts() method to import the fonts for my app. However I get the following error but I thought I didn't need to use Font.loadasync with the Google Fonts (as per docs [here](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-custom-fonts/)). Can you let me know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet, Platform } from 'react-native'
import { useFonts, Kanit_400Regular, Kanit_500Medium, Kanit_700Bold } from '@expo-google-fonts/kanit';
import Colors from '../constants/Colors'

const Header = props => {

  useFonts({Kanit_400Regular, Kanit_500Medium, Kanit_700Bold})

  return (
    <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
      <View style={styles.logo}>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>HEADER</Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        <Text style={{...styles.headerText, fontSize: 14 }}>LOGIN</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
} 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  headerContainer: {
    padding: 15,
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 40 : 15,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    height: Platform.OS === 'android' ? '12%' : '10%',
    borderBottomColor: Colors.borderGold,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: Colors.primary,
    fontFamily: 'Kanit_500Medium',
  }
})

export default Header
```

[image]

Comment: The render happened before the fonts loaded. Load fonts on app launch [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72274869/18341393)

Comment: Could you please add your package.json so we know which version of Expo you're using?

Answer (score 6):

In my case the problem was an incompatible version of `expo-font` in the package.json with the version of expo installed.

I downgraded from `10.1.0` to `10.0.4` and the fonts are now loading fine.

Remember to use `expo install expo-font`

I hope this helps

Comment: Could you please add your package.json so we know which version of Expo you're using?

Comment: Had similar issue, but downgraded from `10.2.0` to `10.1.0`.

Comment: I cannot believe I wasted several hours on this, and this solved it! I had used npm to install... I guess whatever the latest is, isn't compatible with Expo yet. What a pain! Would be great if they added some error handling!!!!!!!!!

Comment: The recommended way to install expo packages is to run `expo install package-name`. You can also fix incompatible package version with `expo doctor --fix-dependencies`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I installed `expo-font` with `yarn`. To fix this issue, I uninstalled  `expo-font` and used the command `npx expo install expo-font` to install expo-font and the issue disappeared

This installation method picks the compatible `expo-font` with your `expo` version. @Marco solution gave me this clue.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `fontWeight` property and directly importing and utilizing the font did the trick.

Modify from:

```
fontFamily: "Manrope",
fontSize: 20,
fontWeight: "600",
lineHeight: 26,
letterSpacing: -0.02,
```

To:

```
fontFamily: "Manrope_600SemiBold",
fontSize: 20,
lineHeight: 26,
letterSpacing: -0.02,
```

Thanks to [this](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8020#issuecomment-662995734) answer on Github.

```
// In your FontLoader.js file:
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import {
  Manrope_500Medium,
  Manrope_600SemiBold,
  Manrope_700Bold,
} from "@expo-google-fonts/manrope";
```